# TFS display all checked out files, grouped by user

Tags: tfs

I know how to display all checked out files in TFS either by using "Find in Source Control" or using the `tf status /user:*` command from the vs command prompt.

How do I display the list grouped by user with the number of files they have checked out?

I want to send out a report scolding users that have somehow managed to checkout 200+ files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to copy the output generated by "Find in Source Control" and pasting it in an Excel spreadsheet (Although there is no Copy option in the context menu, you can still copy the output by pressing `Ctrl+A` to select the entire output and then `Ctrl+C` to do the copy).

Once you have the output in the Excel spreadsheet, then you can use one of the solutions in the below link (I haven't tried them out) to count the number of files checked out per user:

https://superuser.com/questions/189762/excel-how-to-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-range

Comment: What is this "Find in Source Control" you speak of? I'm using VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [TFS Power tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) you can then right click on any folder in Source Control Explorer and select "Find in source control" > "Status"